# How to read and write on pandas df wilth multiple threads?

Tags: python-3.x, multithreading, pandas, locking

Suppose I have a pandas df wil 2 columns containing urls. I would like to add 2 additional columns where I am pulling the their contents.

```
col1   |   col2   
url         url
url         url
url         url
```

Since this task has lots of waiting for servers, I wold like to perform this task on 2 separate threads, one for each column as so:

```
df['col1_content'] = df['col1_content'].apply(getcontent) #on thread 1
df['col2_content'] = df['col2_content'].apply(getcontent) #on thread 2
```

How can I accomplish this task, while having 2 threads writing on and reading from my dataframe? Where would I have to add the `threading.lock.acquire()` and `.release`

Comment: Hi, did you have any luck with this?

Comment: been a while, but no. I think I ended up doing something else, like writing on 2 files.